# Barr bodies in males?

Tags: human-biology, genetics

[This](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=_JdZN69AecoC&pg=RA1-PR36&lpg=RA1-PR36&dq=barr%20bodies%200-4%25%20in%20males&source=bl&ots=CmFMuj2WMc&sig=yxCTRZmf3HJ9w1rV56oB37RGlhw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiOluuElLTXAhVIpI8KHXRqC3cQ6AEIQzAF#v=onepage&q=barr%20bodies%200-4%25%20in%20males&f=false) source states that there are Barr bodies in 0-4% of males.

Why isn't it complete 0%? why some males loose their only X chromosome? How does then their body compensates for those genes which are inactivated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To understand how the X inactivation can occur in, it requires a bit of understanding of how Barr bodies come about.

The main key players to keep in mind are (From 1):

1. **Xist:** Xist   Required for initiation of X-inactivation
2. **Tsix:** Tsix (It's Xist spelled backwards!) Represses Xist expression by silencing the Xist promoter, also required for X-chromosome pairing, counting the number of XICs (X-inactivated chromosomes)

From 2, Here is a general diagram of how X-inactivation occurs.

[image]

X-inactivation requires first, count how many X chromosomes are present (n). Then, the (n-1) number of X chromosomes are inactivated. The choice for which gets inactivated is largely random.

Therefore, if a male has multiple X-chromosomes (as in the case of Klinefelter syndrome) then X-inactivation would occur in males. However, there is also the case that erroneous counting may lead to the inactivation of the only X chromosome in males early in a developing embryo. But this is lethal, and the embryo would die.

More about Kleinfelter Syndrome can be found here: [Klinefelter syndrome](https://ghr.nlm.nih.gov/condition/klinefelter-syndrome)

1. [Guided by RNAs: X-inactivation as a model for lncRNA function.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23816838)
2. [Lessons from X-chromosome ina ctivation: long ncRNA as guides and tethers to the epigenome](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2725936/)

Comment: So all males with Barr bodies are Klinefelter males?

Comment: If they only have 1 X-chromsome and is inactivated, they would not make it to full term. They can have more than XXY, however, there will always be multiple X's.